# How to combine two 8-bit numbers to 16-bit in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, gyroscope

I'm working on the data from a GY-87 (acc and gyro sensor module), The data I have received from it is of the form ACCEL_YOUT_HIGH & ACCEL_YOUT_LOW for the Y axis specifying the HIGH and the LOW value respectively. I've been told that "High and Low registers are 8-bit in nature, therefore the combination of both will be a 16-bit signed data". But I really can't figure out how to combine them to 16 bit data. Here is a sample: ACCEL_YOUT_HIGH=254 ACCEL_YOUT_LOW=144

I've already tried the JAVAScript way, but its not working in octave.

```
var number8Bit1 = firstNumber & 0xff;
var number8Bit2 = ((firstNumber >> 8) & 0xff);
```

Comment: That would be going the other way around. `(high << 8) | low` would be combining

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen but the '<<' operator is not working in Octave.

Comment: It’s the same as multiplying by 256 and adding, possibly fixing sign after

Comment: Yes, `<<` is not an operator in Octave. Instead, use the `bitshift` function.

Comment: Or use typecast

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can you pls provide an example to the syntax like for converting ACCEL_YOUT_HIGH=254 ACCEL_YOUT_LOW=144  to 16 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is 16-bit signed, I think the most elegant solution, is using [typecast](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) (as Andy commented).

For typecast solution to work correctly you cad to do the following:

1. Cast each value to `uint8`
2. Build an array from the two `uint8` elements (put the lower element first, because our systems are [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness))
3. Use `typecast` for converting the two bytes to single `int16` element.
4. Cast the result to `double` (you can skip this part, but it's a common practice - in case you need to apply computations to result).

Code sample:

```
high = 254;
low = 144; 
res = double(typecast([uint8(low), uint8(high)], 'int16'))
```

Result:

```
res = -368
```

---

In case you want to use pure mathematical operations (as Sami commented), you can do it as following:

```
res = high*256 + low;
if (res >= 2^15)
    res = res - 2^16; %Correct the sign.
end
```

I find it less elegant, because the `if` statement is unclear...

---

You can also use [bitshift](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html), `bitor` and `typecast` (as Cris commented).
It looks like the C code `res = (short)((high << 8) | low)`:

```
res = typecast(uint16(bitor(bitshift(high, 8), low)), 'int16');
```

I find it less elegant than the first solution because shift and or operations are not natural in MATLAB / Octave...

Comment: For a MATLAB implementation, I would definitely go with `typecast`. I suspect it would also be the fastest of the 3 options anyway.